# How make video call with ejabberd?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, xmpp, ejabberd

How make video call with ejabberd ( like msn and skype ) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ejabberd doesn't handle audio/video natively. Audio and video is handled through the Jingle (XEP-0166), which is client-to-client.

If you want to place audio or video calls you should make sure both clients support Jingle through normal serivce discover means (see section 11 of XEP-0166). There aren't a lot of clients that do this right now, but Psi, at least, supports it in more recent builds.

Comment: Since this is the first google result for a couple of relevant searches let me update this answer: Several more clients support XEP-0166 nowadays, including pidgin, empathy, and more (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jingle_%28protocol%29)

Comment: Pix-Art Messanger =>2.4.0 suports XEP-0215, but the UDP "connection" is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Jingle Nodes (http://jinglenodes.org) in combination with [SIP Communicator](http://sip-communicator.org) which supports Audio and Video via Jingle through any XMPP Server.

You can also try out quick with Openfire Jingle Nodes plugin.