# Does it requires any configuration changes for audio/video chat through locally installed ejabberd server?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have installed and configured ejabberd locally, using Pidgin as a client. My question is, how can I use a local ejabberd server for audio/video chat? Do I need to install any other module, or make any configuration changes in `ejabberd.cfg`?  (I am using Centos 6, 32-bit.)

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461083/how-make-video-call-with-ejabberd/2773983).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio and video using the XMPP jingle protocols works out of the box with every XMPP compliant server. There is no additional configuration required.

Comment: May I know did you successfully use any XMPP client with ejabberd server to support video chat? what client you used? thanks

Comment: @alex How to install jingle for my ejabberd server?

Comment: there is nothing you need to install on your server to make Jingle work