# OpenFire Server Audio and Video chat

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I want to make a desktop application that can do audio, video call and text chat.
I started the work using the OpenFire server. After implementing text chat, I couldn't find any help for audio and video chat for desktop using OpenFire Server.

Can you all help me regarding audio and video chat in OpenFire or any other server that provides the API for audio, video and text chat?

Comment: As noted in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847746/does-it-requires-any-configuration-changes-for-audio-video-chat-through-locally), audio and video are a client-side feature in XMPP.  No special server module is needed.

Comment: But i am using OpenFire Client. with Smack API.